# Proving the limit of tan(1/x) does not exist

Tags: limits

Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} |\tan(1/x)|$ does not exist.

No clue on how to attack this one.

Comment: What happens to $1/x$ when $x\to0$? What does the graph of the tangent function look like?

Comment: And what happens if you do a substitution, say 1/x = t. What does the problem then look like?

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Consider $u = \frac 1x$. Then as $x \to 0, \;\; u \to \infty:$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left|\tan\left(\frac 1x\right)\right| = \lim_{u\to \infty} |\tan u|$$

[Graph of $|\tan(u)|$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y+%3D+%7Ctan%281%2Fu%29%7C&assumption=%22UnitClash%22+-%3E+%7B%22u%22%2C+%7B%22AtomicMassUnit%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22u%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Variable%22%7D)

[image]

Comment: Nice hint and graphic - +1 from me!

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @amWhy:┼❀excellent❀(◕ ‿ ◕)✓

Comment: @amWhy:(✿◠‿◠)Your welcome`,+.*`,+.*`,+.*`,°*`’°`,+.*`,+.*`,+ `,+.*`,+.*,+.*’`,+.*`,+.*`,+.*``,+.*`,+.*`,+

Answer (score 4):

Find two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $x_n,y_n\to 0$, $\left|\tan\frac1{x_n}\right|=\alpha$ for all $n$, $\left|\tan\frac1{y_n}\right|=\beta$ for all $n$, and $\alpha\ne\beta$. Use the periodic nature of the tangent function to help you choose the sequences (and pick some nice values $\alpha,\beta$, like $\sqrt 3$, for example).

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: For example, $\tan\frac\pi4=1,$ and the tangent function has period $\pi$. Thus, for every positive integer $n$, we have $$1=\left|\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\pi n\right)\right|=\left|\tan\frac{(4n+1)\pi}4\right|.$$ Can you use that to define $x_n$? Similarly define $y_n$, choosing a different value than $1$. Two distinct constant sequences *can't* converge to the same limit in the reals. If $\lim_{x\to 0}\left|\tan\frac1x\right|$ existed, then for any sequence $z_n$ of non-zero points converging to $0$, $\left|\tan\frac1{z_n}\right|$ would converge to said limit. Hence, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If we suppose that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
exists (say $=\ell$) then 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\arctan(\ell)<\infty$$
which is clearly a contradiction.